# Team Foundation Server Version

Tags: tfs

I am interested in evaluating team foundation server and I have downloaded the 2010 trial and ready to install on my server. As part of the evaluation my boss has asked me to have a good idea of the final cost if we decided to use TFS. I have 2 questions in this post really.

1. What components do I need to purchase to be able to use TFS and currently how much do they cost? We have 3-4 developers who would need to use TFS. At the minute one of them is using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
2. After looking around I noticed that TFS11 Express has just launched which looks to be free for upto 5 developers. Is this a viable option for us to use?

I would say the main thing we are looking for is source control.

Kind Regards

Ash

Comment: It is totally possible to use another version control tool with VS projects. I've used both Team Foundation and Svn.

Comment: If your developers are using Visual Studio from an MSDN Professional or higher license subscription, then you can use the full TFS as well. It is included with your MSDN subscription. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy/buy.aspx

Comment: And you might want to consider the TFS Service Preview. Microsoft will provide TFS as a service where they take care of the installation and maintenance and you get all the great goodies. Pricing hasn't been announced yet. But I'd certainly take it into consideration See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/06/04/team-foundation-services-updates-6-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks but its unlikely we will be getting the MSDN version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I would definitely consider Team Foundation Server 2012 Express or Full (formerly code named TFS "11")  It is a much improved experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll find licensing information at [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).
2. Yes TFS Express will be a totally viable option for your team, if all you need is Source Control, some Work Item and some Continuous Integration. This edition is made for small teams such as yours and you wouldn't have to pay for a CAL.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this is only an option if we use VS2012?

Comment: No, you'll be able to use TFS Express with VS2010 too.

Comment: Looks like there are 2 versions of TFS express. Would I want TFS 2012 express or TFS 11 Express?

Comment: TFS 11 Express is a early beta, TFS 2012 express is the same product in it's latest before RTM version. Then go fo TFS 2012 Express

Answer (score 1):

As you have less than 5 developers and just looking for Source Control. Team Foundation Express will be viable option.